# Dijkstra's Algorithm on a Directed Graph with Negative Edges Only Leaving the Source

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

I've been trying to figure out if Dijkstra's algorithm will always succeed on a directed graph that can have edges with negative weights leaving the source vertex only (all other edges are positive), assuming no negative cycles.

I'm inclined to believe that Dijkstra's algorithm WILL always work in this case, since the fact that only edges leaving the source can be negative seems to prevent the issue where the algorithm would not take into account negative edges further along in the graph when finding the shortest paths to a given node, but I just wanted to get a sanity check to make sure that I wasn't completely missing something. That, and I've been unable to come up with a counter-example that would disprove this.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Nope, you can still have a negative cycle here.

Comment: I'm assuming that there are no negative cycles.

Comment: What you need to prove is that the shortest path from source to those vertices is the one by those edges. If you have no negative cycles, then you can add a constant to **all** outgoing edges from the source and have them positive with no worries (only subtract that constant from the result).

Answer (score 1):

It does work just the way you think!

Look at the proof at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness). The fact that all the edges are assumed positive is used when they say that `dist[w]>dist[v]` is a contradiction because as there can not be a negative weighted path from `w` to `v`, `v` must come first.

Here it continues to be a contradiction because otherwise, there would be a negative weighted path from `w` to `v`, which means it uses a negative edge, that is an edge from `source`, which is absurd because that would mean `dist[w]>dist[w,source]`, i.e. a negative cycle.

**BONUS**

I'll proof that the approach proposed in `@dtldarek`'s comment is also correct.

- It is trivial that the shortest path from `source` to `target` uses no return edges to `source`, thus the shortest path can be selected from the set $P$ of those paths which don't return to `source` ever.
- It is also clear that every path in $P$ uses exactly once one of the outgoing edges from `source`. (We may assume `source` is not the same node as `target`).

Therefore by adding a constant $K$ to every outgoing edge from `source` so that they are all positive, all the paths in $P$ will increase their lengths by $K$. If we call $P'$ this set of modified paths, we can claim

$min\{length(p) : p \in P\} \\
=min\{length(p)+K-K : p \in P\} \\
=min\{length(p)+K : p \in P\}-K \\
=min\{length(p') : p' \in P'\}-K$

and conclude that it suffices running dijkstra on the modified graph and substrating K.

Comment: You're assuming that there are no negative cycles through the origin, right? (A comment said you can assume so, so that's fine.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I assume